# Sort results by a field that contains names and surname

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I wonder if it is possible in MySQL to order my results via a name column that contains firstname and surnames.

**Exemple :**

> "title" : Albert CATERSON - Barabara ABELS - Chris WASPINK

```
SQL .. 
ORDER BY title
```

**The result will be:**

> Albert CATERSON - Barabara ABELS - Chris WASPINK

**But I want to sort my results by surname :**

> ABELS Barabara - CATERSON Albert - WASPINK Chris

Do you know if it is possible to do it in mysql? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS OrderBySurname;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.01 sec)


CREATE TABLE OrderBySurname(id INT, title VARCHAR(255));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.26 sec)


INSERT INTO `OrderBySurname` (`id`, `title`) VALUES ('1','Albert CATERSON'),('2', 'Barabara ABELS'),('3', 'Chris WASPINK');
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0


SELECT title , SUBSTRING_INDEX(title, ' ', -1) AS sur_name FROM OrderBySurname ORDER BY sur_name;
+-----------------+----------+
| title           | sur_name |
+-----------------+----------+
| Barabara ABELS  | ABELS    |
| Albert CATERSON | CATERSON |
| Chris WASPINK   | WASPINK  |
+-----------------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)


SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(title, ' ', -1),' ',SUBSTRING_INDEX(title, ' ', 1)) FROM OrderBySurname ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(title, ' ', -1);
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(title, ' ', -1),' ',SUBSTRING_INDEX(title, ' ', 1)) |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ABELS Barabara                                                             |
| CATERSON Albert                                                            |
| WASPINK Chris                                                              |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **order** by surname, you need to use [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

`ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(title, ' ', -1);`

However, if you want also surname to appear first, you gonna need something like that:
`SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(title, ' ', -1), ' ', SUBSTRING_INDEX(title, ' ', 1))`